Crear reportes con Visual Studio Community 2019 con .NET 5.0
Deseo desarrollar una aplicación de Windows Forms con Visual Studio Community 2019, deseo hacerlo con .NET 5.0, pero por más que busco, no encuentro opciones de visor de reportes (ReportViewer) compatibles con .NET 5.0.
Las opciones con .NET Framework 4.8 las conozco, pero deseo saber si puedo o no hacerlo en .NET 5.0
Agradecería cualquier respuesta o información que me permita saber si es posible o no.
Gracias por su atención.

.net-5 ya no tiene soporte, la versión 6 todavía la están manteniendo pero ya murió igual, las que deberías usar son .net 8 y .net 9 quizás con esas versiones encuentras lo que necesitas

Si tu reporte tiene que ser creado desde elementos de la base de datos y cuentas con los recursos económicos puedes utizar Microsoft Report Builder.
